# Which Java PDF library lets me print different parts of the page with different orientation?

Tags: java, pdf

I want to print an a4 sized page which has eight section, some of the sections upside down, and some of the sections sideways. Which PDF libraries allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that iText can do this by using an itext PDFPTable and rotating the cells within the table